# Create new dataframe showing all the hours difference between 2 dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have dataframe

| Employee ID | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10100 | 2001-02-09 10:00 | 2001-02-09 11:30 |
| 10101 | 2001-02-10 10:00 | 2001-02-10 10:30 |
| 10102 | 2001-02-11 11:00 | 2001-02-11 13:00 |
|  |  |  |

I am trying to create a new df as below to list all the times within 1 hour difference between Start Date and End Date

| Employee ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 10100 | 2001-02-09 10:00 |
| 10100 | 2001-02-09 11:00 |
| 10101 | 2001-02-10 10:00 |
| 10102 | 2001-02-11 11:00 |
| 10102 | 2001-02-11 12:00 |
| 10102 | 2001-02-11 13:00 |

I am trying to create a lop to include the logic, but it didn't work well

```
date = []
while Start < End:
    Start += timedelta(hours=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) per hours with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Start'], x['End'], freq='H'), axis=1)

df = df.explode('Date')[['Employee ID','Date']]
print (df)
   Employee ID                Date
0        10100 2001-02-09 10:00:00
0        10100 2001-02-09 11:00:00
1        10101 2001-02-10 10:00:00
2        10102 2001-02-11 11:00:00
2        10102 2001-02-11 12:00:00
2        10102 2001-02-11 13:00:00
```